# Synchronize three slider bar for sum value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How synchronize three slider bar for sum value ?

for example:

```js
    function showValue(newValue) {
      document.getElementById("range-one").innerHTML = newValue;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="sliderBarTwo" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value)">
<span id="range-one">0</span>
```

but here i see only one value

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by  three slider bar for sum value? I only see one slider. The input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many different ways, here is one example if you are really stuck.

```js
function showValue(newValue, resultDiv) {
  document.getElementById(resultDiv).innerHTML = newValue;
  updateSum();
}

function updateSum() {
  var sliderOneValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarOne').value;
  var sliderTwoValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo').value;
  var sliderThreeValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarThree').value;
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sliderOneValue + sliderTwoValue + sliderThreeValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="sliderBarOne" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value, 'range-one')">
<span id="range-one">0</span>
<br>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarTwo" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value, 'range-two')">
<span id="range-two">0</span>
<br>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarThree" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="showValue(this.value, 'range-three')">
<span id="range-three">0</span>
<br>Sum: <span id="sum">0</span>
```